# Convert to typeorm

Tags: typeorm

```
const queryBuilder = this.connection
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .select("a.*")
      .addSelect(
        `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM assessment_attempts aa WHERE aa.assessment_id = a.id AND aa.assessment_attempt_status = '${ProgressEnum.INVITED}')`,
        "invited"
      )
      .addSelect(
        `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM assessment_attempts aa WHERE aa.assessment_id = a.id AND aa.assessment_attempt_status = '${ProgressEnum.INPROGRESS}')`,
        "inProgress"
      )
      .addSelect(
        `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM assessment_attempts aa WHERE aa.assessment_id = a.id AND aa.assessment_attempt_status = '${ProgressEnum.COMPLETED}')`,
        "completed"
      )
      .addSelect(
        `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM assessment_attempts aa WHERE aa.assessment_id = a.id AND aa.assessment_attempt_status = '${ProgressEnum.TERMINATED}')`,
        "terminated"
      )
      .from(Assessment, "a")
      .andWhere("a.org_id=:orgId", { orgId });
```

My code is in nestjs and postgres.

Please help me convert this to typeorm. The above uses select which I don't want.